# R accessing DB query results by column and row number

Tags: r, syntax, comparison

I am new to R language. I have successfully loaded a query's resultset into a variable. Now I want to access the resultset data by column name and row number. And I need to verify if it is Null (it is shown as < NA > in result) then send a mail by bat file with PHP. My sample code is below.

```
library(RODBC)
newconn = odbcConnect("db", uid="uid", pwd="pwd") 
new <- sqlQuery(newconn,"SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1;", errors = TRUE, 1)
if(new$COL1[3] == "<NA>"){
system("sendmail.bat")
}else{
print ("failed")
}
```

Also I would like to compare a string result like below.

```
if(new$COL2[10] == 'MYSTRING'){
print("success")
}
```

But I think I am using wrong syntax. Please help as I am not able to get the correct syntax for doing these comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# I'd avoid new as a variable name
newdata <- sqlQuery(newconn,"SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE1;", errors = TRUE, 1)

# index data frame by row number and column name

if (newdata[3, "COL1"] == "someValue") {
     print("found someValue")
} else {
     print ("failed")
}
```

You can also do

```
if (newdata[3, 2] == "MYSTRING")
```

to index by row and column index.

Lastly, testing for NA is different than string comparison -- you need `is.null()` or `is.na()` as this may get converted by the ODBC access.

Comment: Thank you very much. is.na() is the one I was searching for.